# CURL POST input data values in form for retrieving data

Tags: http, curl, post

I'm trying to retrieve data from the following URL using the CURL command.

http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/OrderList.aspx

The command that I'm using is:

```
curl --data "OrderDate=2016-12-22&AppYear0=2016&FiledBy=A&BenchList=MUM&AppealTypeList=Income%20Tax" http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/OrderList.aspx
```

I get the same page returned. It looks like I'm not passing the right data fields for the form.

Is there a way to identify what fields are being submitted when the "submit" button is clicked?

(I'm using the Tribunal Order Date = 2016-12-22 and Appeal Filing Year = 2016. All others are default values that are displayed when the page opens)

Comment: please show what you made on the curl

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran do you mean what I got from curl? The curl command I used is in the question-post.

Comment: The curl command U used for post

Comment: You might take a look in the Network tools of your browser to identify which fields are submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to identify what fields are being submitted when the
>   "submit" button is clicked?

using your browser network monitor , for instance, in [firefox Network request details Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Network_request_details) you can view the posted parameters via `params` tab

[image]

you also can copy the full curl command by right clicking the link and choose `copy as cURL`

Comment: thanks this was helpful. Could do this on chrome by pressing "F12" > Network > Copy as curl. I have a follow up question after this at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671742/curl-command-for-a-post-that-redirects-302-response